# Invalid ruote rule to catch request from vue-tables-2 component

Tags: laravel, routes

Using vue-tables-2 component in my @vue/cli 4.0.5 app
I see that GET request generated

```
http://local-ctasks-api.com/api/adminarea/activity-logs-filter?query=&limit=10&ascending=1&page=1&byColumn=0
```

and I try in Laravel 6 Backend REST API to set route to catch it as :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth',  'prefix' => 'adminarea', 'as' => 'adminarea.'], function ($router) {
    Route::get('activity-logs-filter?query={query}&limit={limit}&ascending={ascending}&page={page}&byColumn={column}', 'API\Admin\ActivityLogController@filter');
```

But I got 404 error,

Is my route invalid ?

**UPDATED  # 1:**
Yes, var with “/api” was unaccesible. I fixed it and running request without “/adminarea”

```
http://local-ctasks-api.com/api/activity-logs-filter?query=&limit=10&ascending=1&page=1&byColumn=0
```

I moved route definition out of any block :

```
Route::get('activity-logs-filter?query={query}&limit={limit}&ascending={ascending}&page={page}&byColumn={column}', 'API\Admin\ActivityLogController@filter');
```

I got error in browser :

```
"error": "INCORRECT ROUTE"
```

with control action defined in app/Http/Controllers/API/Admin/ActivityLogController.php :

```
public function filter( $query, $limit, $ascending, $page, $column )
{
    \Log::info('!!++ filter $this->requestData ::');
    \Log::info(print_r(  $this->requestData, true  ));
```

Why error ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot put `api` on `prefix`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth',  'prefix' => 'api/adminarea', 'as' => 'adminarea.'], function ($router) {
```

**EDIT**:

Don't put parameter on route like that, use `Request` instance

```
Route::get('activity-logs-filter,'API\Admin\ActivityLogController@filter');
```

and controller

```
public function filter(Request $request){
    $query = $request->query;
    $limit = $request->limit;
    $ascending = $request->ascending;
    $page = $request->page;
    $column = $request->column;
```

dont forget `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` on your controller

Comment: Pls look at UPDATED  # 1

Comment: @PetroGromovo I've updated my answer, please take a look